# Why the excess of 3 children underneath the mango tree?

Tags: lyrics, history, film

In the song *Underneath the Mango Tree* the refrain goes:

> Mango, banana and tangerine
> Sugar and ackee and cocoa bean
> When we get marry we make them grow
> And nine little chil' in a row

https://www.songlyrics.com/monty-norman/under-the-mango-tree-lyrics/

I liked this song because of the lovely, poetic idea of cultivating a crop for each child. Then I counted...

Fair enough, it would be hard to squeeze another triplet of fruits into the meter. But why not **six (6)** children, though?